# Q: Powershell - read and report special characters from file

Tags: powershell

I've got a huge directory listing of files, and I need to see what special characters exist in the file names - specifically nonstandard characters like you'd get using ALT codes.

I can export a directory listing to a file easily enough with:

```
get-childitem -path D:\files\ -File -Recurse >output.txt
```

What I need to do however, is pull out the special characters, and only the special characters from the text file. The only way I can think to easily quantify everything "special" (since there are a ton of possibilities in the that character set) would be to compare the text against a list of characters I'd want to keep, stored in a joined variable (a-z, 0-9, etc)

I can't quite figure out how to pull out the "good" characters, leaving only the special ones. Any ideas on where to start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take "special" characters to be anything that falls outside US ASCII.

That basically means any character with a numerical value of 128 or more, easy to inspect in a `Where-Object` filter:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse |Where-Object {
    $_.Name.ToCharArray() -gt 127
}
```

This will return all files containing "special" characters in their name.

---

If you want to extract the special characters themselves, per file, use `ForEach-Object`:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse |ForEach-Object {
    if(($Specials = $_.Name.ToCharArray() -gt 127)){
        New-Object psobject -Property @{File=$_.FullName;Specials=$(-join $Specials)}
    }
}
```

Comment: Your first solution may just work - plus it is remarkably simple, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look at piping your results to Select-String.  With Select-String you can specify a list of regex values to search for.